# @googlemaps/jest-mocks autocompleteService.getPlacePredictions not returning the predictions response

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have source code:

```
let service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
      service.getPlacePredictions({
        input: "123",
        componentRestrictions: {country: "us"}
      }, (predictions, status) => {
        if (status !== google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          return;
        }
        setLocationPredictions(predictions)
      });
```

I have written test case:

```
import {
    AutocompleteService,
    initialize,
    Map,
    Marker,
    mockInstances,
    PlacesService,
    PlacesServiceStatus
} from "@googlemaps/jest-mocks";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
...
...
it("test") {
    const autocompleteService = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
    let response = autocompleteService.getPlacePredictions({
            input: '111',
            componentRestrictions: {country: 'us'},
    });
    console.log("response: ", response);
}
```

I am getting the response as "Promise { { predictions: [] } }".

1. Will I be able to mock getPlacePredictions function in source code in this way?
2. Why am I not getting the predictions in the response?
   Requesting for the help here. Thanks in advance.

Tried to mock AutocompleteService.getPlacePredictions using @googlemaps/jest-mocks But not able to mock it.